# CakePHP call second Controller Method after initial Ajax Call

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I'm aware that this approach is a little dirty, but suppose I had one method in my controller myMethod() which may be called by http request method(GET/POST) as also by an regular method call (this->myMethod())

The question is: how do I may distnguish which call method has been used inside this method?

Comment: So, the `second` function can be accessed directly by browsers through various methods, and `first` can too, but when `first` is called via Ajax you need it to do what `second` does when it's called via a standard `get`? Safe to assume that `second` has pieces of functionality outside of the request-specific `if` block?

Comment: The first metod will be called only by ajax call. The problem occures,  when I try to call the second method from within the first method via this->second($itemID). It gets detected as an ajax call  whereas $this->second() is definietly not an Ajax call, and that results in an inproper return result. I strongly assume that Cakephp has some build in functionality that do not distinguish between those two request call an treat them both as ajax request. So the question is how to overcome it?

Comment: When you call a function, it's still all happening within the same request, so when it's the request that you're checking (per the code you've shown), then yeah, it thinks it's Ajax. The specifics of your scenario are still extremely vague, so it's hard to suggest what the best solution might be. Maybe you should be splitting the common functionality out of the `second` function into something that doesn't care about the request type, for example. Maybe you should be calling `second` via a separate HTTP request. There are likely other possibilities as well. If you add more code, it might help.

Comment: that will definitely work, i've had tried this already. But that results on an uncontrolled number of method calls which do the same but for diffrent request type.  I would like to avoid this approach.

Comment: Share some more code, then, even just pseudo code that makes it clear where the blocks of functionality lie in relation to the "if Ajax" logic.

Comment: @GregSchmidt, I had updated the question to clarify the issue a little.

Comment: You could pass a parameter to the function in the case of calling internally, which wouldn't be present when calling through a browser action, but that's ugly. This still feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and an overall cleaner solution could be arrived at by backing up a little bit.